# React Native "if" statement behaviour? Early exit or full evaluation?

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

Does an "if" statement with multiple "or" operators exit when the first condition returns true, or are all conditions evaluated?

i.e. does the order of your conditions matter?

**Example scenario:**

A shouldComponentUpdate() function with an if statement and the evaluated conditions vary in cost.

Does the order of the conditions (with the least expensive first) promise an improvement in performance or will the entire if statement get evaluated even if the first condition will return a true?

**For example:**

Assume an if statement in the form:

```
if ( (this.props.value != nextProps.value) || (deepDiffer(object1, object2) )
```

If `(this.props.value != nextProps.value)` returns `true`, will the code still evaluate the `deepDiffer`? Or will it immediately enter the if statement and execute the conditional code?

Comment: Nothing to do with React; this is about basic JavaScript semantics, and yes when the left side of `||` evaluates to something truthy the right-hand side will **not** be evaluated.

Comment: Great, thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: These type of operators are short circuit operators, `&&` does the same if the first is false it won't evaluate the second one. you can however have eager operators (i think they called) that will check regardless.

Comment: @Sasha Brilliant! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Javascript, so yes, it exits when the first condition is true.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical):

> As logical expressions are evaluated left to right, they are tested
>   for possible "short-circuit" evaluation using the following rules:
>
> - **false** && *anything* is short-circuit evaluated to false.
> - **true** || *anything* is short-circuit evaluated to true.
>
> The rules of logic guarantee that these evaluations are always correct. Note that the *anything* part of the above expressions is not evaluated, so any side
>   effects of doing so do not take effect.

Answer (score 1):

In a condition, if there are multiple 'or', they are checked from left to right and if the first is `true`, it won't check the nexts.

Same behaviour in a 'and' chain, when the first `false` is encounter, the nexts won't be checked

This is basic Javascript